# Class in buildpath-jar still not found

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I'm developing a eclipse plugin rcp and I'm running into a NoClassDefFoundError

```
Exception in thread "Thread-7" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jdom/input/SAXBuilder  
    at org.geonames.WebService.search(WebService.java:783)  
    at geo.GeocoderGeonames$SearchThread.run(GeocoderGeonames.java:119)  
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder  
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:483)  
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:399)  
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)  
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:87)  
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)  
    ... 2 more
```

The class that supposedly cannot be found is in a jar that I have added to the buildpath. I don't get any compile error etc only this exception when the running application enters the code where this class is needed...

Is there some other place I need to add the jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading [this](http://www.eclipsezone.com/articles/eclipse-vms/) added the jar to the MANIFEST.MF, which solved the problem.
As I understand it, eclipse starts several classloaders which only sees what MANIFEST.MF tells them to see and ingnores the build path...

Answer (score 0):

How are you running your plug-in? You may need to add the JAR to the class path in the VM arguments.

Answer (score 0):

In our experience a `NoClassDefFoundError` can sometimes mean that more than one version of a Class are found, as there is also a `ClassNotFoundException` that's normally thrown if a class cannot be found.

Another reason in your case (XML parser) might be something with endorsed classes. Are you directly importing the jdom classes or something like org.w3c...? If so, have a look at the "endorsed classes" system of Java, something that I just recently came across.

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError will be thrown if compiled code refers to a class that is not on the classpath.  ClassNotFoundException will be thrown if when trying to use reflection to instantiate a class, the class as named cannot be found.